# rewrite ruels not working in localhost

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

I've tried to rewrite the URL of my website when i upload it online everything will work well but it doesn't work in loaclhost.
am using xampp>Windows7>Apach

Links doesn't work the way i rewrite it

example this wont work: http://localhost/site/blog/id/1

This is working in local host http://localhost/site/blog.php?id=1

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+questions\.php\?postid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ questions/postid/%1? [R=301,L]
#RewriteRule ^questions/postid/([^/]+)/?$ questions.php?postid=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on
#"/questions.php?postid=123" to "/questions/postid/123"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /questions\.php\?postid=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /questions/postid/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^questions/postid/([^/]+)/?$ /questions.php?postid=$1 [L,QSA]
#rewrite "file" to "file.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: it worked but on the next page it show this Object not found!

The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.12 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1l PHP/5.6.8

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the rule. Does the edited rule work?

Comment: Sorry this edited copy is not working at all @starkeen